# JavaScript Faux Pas - Let me put global libraries on the window?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, global

I'm using RequireJS. I absolutely hate the double variable syntax of defining a dependency and passing it in as a variable in a callback function. I am therefore attempting the implement the 'Sugar' syntax available in RequireJS.

However, I only want to 'import' global libraries like Backbone, jQuery, Underscore and Marionette once. jQuery and Backbone obviously assign themselves to the Window object but Underscore and Marionette do not.

This is my main.js file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery" : "vendor/jquery.min",
    "underscore": "vendor/underscore-min",
    "backbone" : "vendor/backbone-min",
    "marionette" : "vendor/marionette",
    "app" : "app/app"
  }
});

define(function(require, exports, module) {

    // Make these libraries available globally
    var jquery          = require('jquery');
    window.underscore   = require('underscore');
    var Backbone        = require('backbone');
    window.marionette   = require('marionette');

    // Require and start our own app
    var app             = require('app');
    app.start();
});
```

This obviously stops me from having to import/require each of these core libraries into every subsequent module/component for my application. Taking my code from potentially this (app.js file):

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {

     var jquery = require('jquery'),
        underscore = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Marionette = require('marionette'),

        // module specific libs
        mymodule = require('../js/app/module'),
        logger   = require('../js/app/logger');

    return {
        start: function () {
            var testview = new mymodule();
            logger.logme();
        }
    }
});
```

To this (better app.js):

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {

    var mymodule = require('../js/app/module'),
        logger   = require('../js/app/logger');

    return {
        start: function () {
            var testview = new mymodule();
            logger.logme();
        }
    }
});
```

Much cleaner IMO.

So thoughts? Criticisms? Are these going to play well together? (two already do it themselves - why not for the other two if they are core to the app).

In my head I don't think it will be a problem as long as I don't start hammering every module/component/library onto the global scope but I'm interested for someone more experienced to weigh in.

If I'm doing it wrong or there is a better way let me know!

Thanks

Comment: If the goal is to escape the bloated requirejs syntax I'd recommend checking out browserify

Comment: Wait, why do your require `jquery, underscore, Backbone, Marionette` at all in your `app.js` when you don't use them there? They should be declared as dependencies of your `module` and `logger` only.

Comment: Because then I won't need to require them in every module I create as they are available globally. I'm trying to get away from to much boilerplate code, I'd be repeating the same requires in logger and module. Also putting them in main.js made more sense to me as its a configuration file.

Comment: Yes, but you want to define your dependencies at as low a level as possible so that you have code that is (1) reusable, (2) testable, (3) refactorable. If that means you declare them several times for several different modules, so be it. RequireJS will ensure you don't load multiple copies of each dependency, so long as you use it properly.

Comment: That make little sense when the dependencies discussed are part of the framework the application is built on? I see what you're saying but putting framework specific dependencies onto the window would not hamper the ability to achieve those 3 things you have listed.

Comment: requirejs load once only each dependency (internally it stores it into a registry object). They are made globally available through the require API, but the only global function you should to deal with  is require/define. The purpose of requirejs is to have a low coupled code where each module knows only the dependencies he uses. Another advantage of requirejs is to avoid the global namespace pollution (which is much more likely to generate bugs than explicitely wrinting your dependencies).

Comment: Yes, but each module should, in theory, be decouplable from the app and individually testable. If your 'logger' requires you to load the app, then you can't test the logger without loading the entire app. Similarly, you couldn't use the logger in a different project. Finally, if you decided you wanted to refactor your code, it would be much more complicated. If all you're worried about is syntax, then my solution below will do the trick. But you really should not get away from loading your dependencies at the lowest level possible or... you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @RichardWatts: then declare a new module "framework" that requires your libraries, installs them globally, and is used as a dependency of every other module.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb comment in light of the above, but would the `require(['backbone', 'jquery'], function (Backbone, jquery) { var model = Backbone.Model. extend ({}) })` overload not, at least, partially meet your needs for lighter code?

Comment: @Seebiscuit I think the issue is, in part, the 'double variable' syntax used by that approach.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After reading your comments, I realized your question has two components. One component is purely syntactical - and my original answer addresses a possible solution to that component. However, to the extent that your solution also incorporates an application design component, whereby dependencies of individual modules are defined at the application level, my answer is that is "bad practice." Dependencies should be defined at the module level (or lower) so that every element of your application is decouplable. This will be an enormous benefit in writing code that is (1) reusable, (2) testable, (3) refactorable. By defining your dependencies at the application level, you force yourself into loading the entire application simply to access a single module, for example, to run a test - and you inhibit rearranging modules or reuse of the same modules in other projects. If you do this, in the long run... you're gonna have a bad time.

Now, to the extent that your question is syntactical...

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** I agree that require.js syntax is ugly as hell, annoying to use, and a potential source of difficult to debug errors. My own approach was to implement the following wrapping function (pardon the coffeescript).

```
# Takes dependencies in the form of a hash of arguments with the format
# { path: "name"}
# Assigns each dependency to a wrapper variable (by default "deps"),
# without the need to list each dependency as an argument of the function.
PrettyRequire = (argHash, callback) ->
    deps = new Array()
    args = new Array()

    #loops through the passed argument, sorts into two arrays.
    for propt of argHash
        deps.push(propt)
        args.push(argHash[propt])

    #calls define using the 'dependency' array   
    define(deps, ()->
        deps = new Array()

        # assigns the resulting dependencies to properties of the deps object
        for arg, i in args
            deps[arg] = arguments[i]

        # runs callback, passing in 'deps' object
        return callback(deps)
    )
```

This code is a simple rewrite which (1) preserves scope and (2) prettifies the syntax. I simply include the function as a part of a internal library that I maintain, and include that library at the outset of any project.

Define can then be called with the following (imho) prettier syntax:

```
PrettyRequire({
    'backbone': 'Backbone'
    'vendor/marionette': 'Marionette'
    '../js/app/module': 'myModule'
}, (deps)->
    Backbone.Model.extend(...) # for dependencies that assign themselves to global
    deps.myModule(...) # for all dependencies (including globals)
)
```

That's my approach, to the extent that it's responsive to your question. It's worth noting also that your apps will take a (small) performance hit as a result of the increased overhead, but as long as you're not calling too many sub modules, it shouldn't be too much of an issue, and to me, it's worth it not to have to deal with the double syntax you describe.